# use ivy java project in maven?

Tags: java, maven, ivy

I have a big maven project with many subprojects that are also maven based.

I started using Red5, and red5 creates an ivy based project. I need to add that project to the dependencies.

list files of project main directory:

```
build.properties  build.xml  ivy.xml  ivysettings.xml  lib  readme.txt  src  www
```

how can I add this project as one of the maven project dependencies ?

using Java with Maven 3.0.4

thanks!
Kfir

Comment: You can JAR it and then add it to your local maven repository. After that, you can put it in your pom.xml

Comment: i prefer not to jar it, just to make it as one of the other projects. I will modify it a lot and to jar it each time will be uncomfortable

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... A `lib` directory in an Ivy project.

You can modify the build.xml to create one more target that calls the [`<ivy:makepom/>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/makepom.html) target. Just make sure that [`<ivy:resolve>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) is called first. This will create a small piece of the `pom.xml` file you need.

As for the rest. What's that technical term? Oh yeah, you're screwed.

The problem is that Ant and Maven have two completely different build philosophies. In Ant, you write a `build.xml` script that describes what you want to build and how you want to build it. In Maven, you *describe* your project via a `pom.xml` file, and Maven does all the build processing for you.

This isn't an issue of whether or not Whether Ant or Maven is the force of all that's good in the world and the other is only for luzers Apple Fanboys. This is a case of manually converting a pre-existing project into Maven.

You'll have to go through your `build.xml` and figure out everything it is doing. Then, you need to convert this over to a Maven `pom.xml` file. There's no way to automate this. Even worse, Red5 isn't setup like a Maven project, so you'll either have to move all the files around, or go into archaic `pom.xml` configuration hell trying to override how Maven assumes the build is suppose to take place. This can take days, even weeks to get right. And, in the end, you end up with a project you don't control that if you want to update will have to be done all over again from scratch.

Trust me, I did this before for another job where the System Architect decided that Maven was better than Ant, and all of our projects must be converted from Ant to Maven. And, who got stuck with this task? Not the developers who were too busy with other tasks, but I the Configuration Manager.

And, in the end, you will have a project you don't control that if you want to update will have to be done all over again from scratch.

---

There is an alternative: Ignore it.

Does it really matter if Red5 is an Ivy project? What do you need from this Red5 project anyway? Do you need that `red5.jar` or the distribution that gets built.

If you need the distribution, let it remain as an Ivy project. Simply set the `ivysettings.xml` to point to your Maven repository and let it know that it's in Maven 2 format. Ivy will have no problems getting stuff out of that. So what if it's Ivy?

If you just need that `red5.jar` file in your other Maven project, you can simply use the `<ivy:makepom/>` task to generate a `pom.xml` file for you. Then use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to deploy that jar into your Maven repository:

```
 $ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=red5.jar \
     -DpomFile=pom.xml \
     -DrepositoryId=$repoId \
     -Durl=$url
```

Now, your `red5.jar` is in your Maven repository as a fully transitive downloading jar. If you really, really want to get fancy, you can embed the generated pom.xml file into the jar itself, so it is *self referential* just like Maven jars are. That will take about 30 minutes of hacking the current build.xml file. (Or, if your jar doesn't have to have the pom.xml embedded in it, a separate Ant file that just builds the `pom.xml` you need, and maybe even deploys it into your Maven repository for you. That way, if the project gets updated, you don't have to worry about the `build.xml` file being updated.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it myself, but I know Ivy has a [task which can convert an ivy file to a maven pom.](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/makepom.html)  I'd explore an option where my CI environment runs that task to generate a pom after a successful build, and then get my maven project to look at the CI's latest artifacts for the jar and pom.  You could skip the CI environment as well, and have maven resolve artifacts from the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to get away without creating a JAR.  Maven's whole dependency philosophy is built around JAR files in a repository - when one maven project depends on another the way it works is that the dependent project builds its JAR and puts it in the local repository, then the main project depends on it from there.

That said, you can fairly easily automate this using a combination of `<ivy:makepom>` and the [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html).  The idea is to make the Ivy project build its JAR and push that to the local Maven repository as part of every build, so it is immediately available for the maven projects to depend on.

```
<jar destfile="project.jar">
   <fileset dir="classes" />
</jar>

<ivy:makepom ivyfile="ivy.xml" pomfile="project.pom" conf="default,runtime">
   <mapping conf="default" scope="compile"/>
   <mapping conf="runtime" scope="runtime"/>
</ivy:makepom>

<artifact:pom id="project.pom" file="project.pom" />
<artifact:install file="project.jar" pomRefId="project.pom" />
```

Make sure your Ivy project has a version number that ends with `-SNAPSHOT` in its `ivy.xml`.